# C# Linq to Sql XML Retrieve Closest Element in Parent

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some wonky XML I'm trying to read values from.

```
<text>
  <term>a</term>
  <line>
    <elm>data here</elm>
  </line>
  <term>b</term>
  <line>
    <elm>data here</elm>
  </line>
  <term>c</term>
  <line>
    <elm>data here</elm>
  </line>
</text>
```

I only have access to the the 3 `line` elements at this point.

As I loop over each line, for the first line I want to find the element `term` that happens to have "a" as a value since it's the "closest" to the first line child.

Same thing for the second line except I want to find the closest `term` element, which in this case is "b"

How can I accomplish this reliably using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `term` element always exactly precedes the `line` element, you can use

```
XElement.ElementsBeforeSelf().Last()
```

So

```
var element = XElement.Load(@"previous-sibling.xml");
var termsQuery =
            from line in element.Descendants("line")
            select new
            {
                Elm = line.Descendants("elm").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                Term = line.ElementsBeforeSelf().LastOrDefault().Value
            };
```

Comment: Thank you! ElementsBeforeSelf is what I was missing.